# How to run a piece of code when addon is just activated

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Is there a way to run a block of code when the user activates the add-on?

I am creating my add-on, in which my add-on appends in a few node groups from other .blend file.

I would like my add-on to directly append the nodes rather than the user having to click some button to do that!

Thanks for help....

Comment: do you mean when you register the addon, or when blender start and the addon is enabled ( registered )?

Comment: Yes, just like that....

Comment: which one exactly?

Comment: blender start and addon is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example addon that will execute the function "load_fonts" when blender starts,  it use the handlers to run a function at blender start :

```
import os
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def load_fonts(scene):
    font_dir = bpy.context.user_preferences.filepaths.font_directory
    for file in os.listdir(font_dir):
        if file.endswith(".ttf"):  
            bpy.data.fonts.load(font_dir+file)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_fonts)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(load_fonts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

you can call the function  you want inside the register() function, but you can't get access to the scene :

```
def load_fonts(scene):
    print("addon activated ")

def register():
    load_fonts()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

to overcome this problem you can use handlers to access the scene as [@CoDEmanX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1363/codemanx) shows in [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?313278-When-to-initialize-custom-scene-variables-in-an-addon) :  example

```
import os
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def load_fonts(scene):
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.remove(load_fonts)
    font_dir = bpy.context.user_preferences.filepaths.font_directory
    for file in os.listdir(font_dir):
        if file.endswith(".ttf"):  
            bpy.data.fonts.load(font_dir+file)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(load_fonts)

def unregister():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: This works when the addon is activated by default. I want it to work even if the user activates it after blender has loaded...

Comment: @Always4u try calling the function inside the `register()` function

Comment: I did not get that, can you please give an example.. :)

Comment: `def  register():   load_fonts()`  but I think you can't access the scene in the register function

Comment: my function needs at least 1 argument, and I don't know how to call it through the register() function!

Comment: `load_fonts(None)` ?

Comment: unregister_class(...):, missing bl_rna attribute from 'RNAMeta' instance (may not be registered)

Comment: sorry but this does not work at all, unregister fails miserably, and on register, the function is NEVER called (blender 2.9)

Answer (score 1):

This might help explain the source of the problem. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes#Restricted_Context

I think we are left with checking every update cycle, so hundreds of times a second via scene_update_pre handler?! super ugly, super wasteful, something is very wrong with this convoluted situation. I, We or They probably need to rethink from some other examples something totally different here.

```
bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(initsetup_operators_needing_scene_function)
```

Comment: Yeah, it does some wasteful. If I understand it correctly, it only happens when a value in the scene is changed though, not every program tick.