# Script works in python console and "run script' but cannot be enabled as an addon

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, add-on, append

I am a beginner in scripting so I am aware that this might be trivial thing, but I will appreciate any help.

I was trying to make some automation to my geometry node workflow.
The main utility of it, is that it should append highlighted nodes from another file to the new file during the installation of the addon and then I should be able to apply the following nodes with the *New panel and Button*.

The problem is that the installation goes successfully, but then I cannot enable the addon although once I put the same code into a text editor and run it, the panel appears and the button correctly recognizes the addon's folder and applies the desired effect. I got this error*when I try to enable it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\PC COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\hardsurface_addon2\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    bpy.ops.wm.append(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 107, in __call__
    _BPyOpsSubModOp._view_layer_update(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 70, in _view_layer_update
    view_layer = context.view_layer
AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'view_layer'
```

This is the addon's folder:[image]

**The full script looks like this now:**

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Hard-Surface Paneler",
    "description": "Applies various procedural effects onto the selected objects.",
    "author": "Krzysztof Galant",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (3, 6, 0),
    "location": "View_3D > UI",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
from bpy.utils import resource_path
from pathlib import Path

USER = Path(resource_path('USER'))
src = USER / "scripts/addons"

file_path = src / "nodes.blend"
inner_path = "NodeTree"
object_paneling = "Paneling"
object_massing = "Massing"
object_shelldevision = "Shell Devision"
object_volume = "Volume to Mesh"

bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath=str(file_path / inner_path / object_paneling),
    directory=str(file_path / inner_path),
    filename=object_paneling,
)

bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath=str(file_path / inner_path / object_massing),
    directory=str(file_path / inner_path),
    filename=object_massing,
)
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath=str(file_path / inner_path / object_shelldevision),
    directory=str(file_path / inner_path),
    filename=object_shelldevision,
)
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath=str(file_path / inner_path / object_volume),
    directory=str(file_path / inner_path),
    filename=object_volume,
)


class OBJECT_OT_ExecuteMyAddon(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.execute_my_addon"
    bl_label = "Execute"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # Loop through the selected objects and apply effect for each object
        for active in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            bpy.context.window.view_layer.objects.active = active  # Set the active object

            # Add Geometry Nodes modifier for Massing
            gn_modifier = active.modifiers.new("Geometry Nodes", type='NODES')
            gn_modifier.name = "Massing"
            massing_node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get("Massing")
            if massing_node_tree:
                gn_modifier.node_group = massing_node_tree

            # Add Geometry Nodes modifier for Volume to Mesh
            gn_modifier = active.modifiers.new("Geometry Nodes", type='NODES')
            gn_modifier.name = "Volume to Mesh"
            volume_node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get("Volume to Mesh")
            if volume_node_tree:
                gn_modifier.node_group = volume_node_tree

            # Add Decimate modifier for Collapse
            decimate_mod_col = active.modifiers.new(name="Decimate", type="DECIMATE")
            decimate_mod_col.ratio = 0.5
            decimate_mod_col.name = "Decimate Collapse"

            # Add Geometry Nodes modifier for Shell Devision
            gn_modifier = active.modifiers.new("Geometry Nodes", type='NODES')
            gn_modifier.name = "Shell Devision"
            massing_node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get("Shell Devision")
            if massing_node_tree:
                bpy.context.object.modifiers["Shell Devision"]["Input_2"] = None
                gn_modifier.node_group = massing_node_tree

            # Add Decimate modifier for Planar
            decimate_mod_plan = active.modifiers.new("Decimate", type='DECIMATE')
            decimate_mod_plan.name = "Decimate Planar"
            decimate_mod_plan.decimate_type = 'DISSOLVE'
            decimate_mod_plan.angle_limit = 0.261799  # radians, which is approximately 15 degrees

            # Add Geometry Nodes modifier for Paneling
            gn_modifier = active.modifiers.new("Geometry Nodes", type='NODES')
            gn_modifier.name = "Paneling"
            massing_node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get("Paneling")
            if massing_node_tree:
                gn_modifier.node_group = massing_node_tree

            # Add Mirror modifier
            mirror_modifier = active.modifiers.new("Mirror", type='MIRROR')
            mirror_modifier.use_axis[0] = True
            bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].use_bisect_axis[0] = True

            bpy.ops.wm.toggle_all_show_expanded()

        print("Operation applied!")
        return {'FINISHED'}


# PANEL CREATION
class MyAddonPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hard-Surface Paneler"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Hard-Surface Paneler'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Display the execute button
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.execute_my_addon", text="Apply")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_ExecuteMyAddon)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyAddonPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_ExecuteMyAddon)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyAddonPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hi. What happens if you remove the .blend file from the addon's folder?

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure I understand your script. You want to append some objects every time your addon is enabled ?

Comment: @curious_1 Nothing happened. I still get the same error. :/

Comment: @Gorgious. If it can be appended just one time not always, that would cool. But I couldn't find a way to do it properly. ( I had the script splitted once, but it also misbehaved so I put everything under the one).

Comment: Use `bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append` like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49879/how-to-run-a-piece-of-code-when-addon-is-just-activated